# mongoDB query using aggregate to query the most recent date of an item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
[
    { product_name: "Orange",vendor_name: "test1", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-06-12T00:00:00.000Z"},
    { product_name: "Orange",vendor_name: "test1", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-02-24T00:00:00.000Z"}, 
    { product_name: "Apple",vendor_name: "test2", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"},
    { product_name: "Apple",vendor_name: "test2", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"} 
]
```

I want to query the collection to find each item's most recent "business_date", and in this example it should be `record #2`, and `record #4`.

How would I go ahead and write an `aggregate` query for this?

I've tried this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $sort: {
            business_date: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
           _id : { vendor_name: "$vendor_name", product_code: "$product_code" },
           business_date: {$first: "$business_date"}
        }
    }, 
    {
        $match: {
            vendor_name: {$in: ["test1", "test2"]},
            category: 'Fruit'
        }
    }
]
db.sales.aggregate(pipeline);
```

But I get nothing returned. I am not really experienced with MongoDB, would somebody let me know what should be the correct( and most operation efficient) way to write this query?

Comment: You are almost there the last match filtered all your results out because after the $group: the id become `_id: { vendor_name: 'test1' }`. Beware the aggration pipeline run one by one from frist to last and the order matters

Comment: Aggregation Pipeline docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first :-)

1. use `$match` as a first pipeline in query to increase processing speed (less data to process)
2. in `$group` you can use `$min` - no sort needed ***speed*** :-)

So query will look like this:

```
db.wab.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                vendor_name : {
                    $in : ["test1", "test2"]
                },
                category : 'Fruit'
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    vendor_name : "$vendor_name",
                    product_name : "$product_name"
                },
                business_date : {
                    $min : "$business_date"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: This is great! thx. just another question, i want to return also the "price" field that's at the minimum business_date, how would I write that query in the $group?

Comment: I create another question for ^^ above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795662/mongodb-query-using-aggregate-to-query-the-most-recent-date-of-an-item-and-retur