# mongoDB query using aggregate to query the most recent date of an item and return the record that's in the most recent date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
[
    { product_name: "Orange",vendor_name: "test1", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-06-12T00:00:00.000Z", "price": 2.00},
    { product_name: "Orange",vendor_name: "test1", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-02-24T00:00:00.000Z", "price": 5.00}, 
    { product_name: "Apple",vendor_name: "test2", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-07-11T00:00:00.000Z", "price": 3.00},
    { product_name: "Apple",vendor_name: "test2", category: "Fruit",  business_date: "2015-06-19T00:00:00.000Z", "price": 6.00} 
]
```

I want to query the collection to find each item's  price  AT the most recent "business_date", and in this example it should be record #2, $5.00, and record #4, $6.00. How would I go ahead and write an aggregate query for this? This is related to [mongoDB query using aggregate to query the most recent date of an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782029/mongodb-query-using-aggregate-to-query-the-most-recent-date-of-an-item/37787185#37787185). 
I tried below :

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            category: {$in: ['Fruit']}
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
           _id : { vendor_name: "$vendor_name", product_code: "$product_code" },
           business_date: {$max: "$business_date"}, 
           price: {$last: "$price"}
        }
    } 
]
db.sales.aggregate(pipeline);
```

But didn't get the result i wanted. any suggestions?

EDIT: I got it to working with the sort function, but wonder if this is logically correct , and if there is a better and more efficient way to achieve the same?:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            category: {$in: ['Fruit']}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            business_date: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
           _id : { vendor_name: "$vendor_name", product_code: "$product_code" },
           business_date: {$max: "$business_date"},
           price: {$first: "$price"}
        }
    } 
];
```

Comment: In order to use `$max`, you need a valid ISO date.

Comment: the $max part works. the price part is where it's incorrect. I want the price where the business_date is max (or most recent)